# Why is CGsize too small when I use UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to load an image, then grab the size of it so that I can use it in a resizing algorithm.

when I use the following code in ViewdidLoad

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};
```

I then need to grab the frame from viewwillappear

```
CGSize trial = self.imageView.frame.size;
CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
```

This is what I get.

[image: error values]

Why is the scrollviewframe have a size of 0,0?

Comment: Why not setting the frame of imageView manually?

Comment: Are you sure that `image` is non-nil when this code is run?

Comment: try adding NSLog(@"%f %f", image.size.height, image.size.width); in the seconds line. it could shed some light.

Comment: Make sure that you have added the image file to your project in XCode - if not, it won't be in the main bundle and the `imageNamed:` selector won't be able to find it. (and no it shouldn't be integer values, CGSize width and height are floats as are all screen dimensions in iOS)

Comment: @rmaddy I have added the image to the file and linked it. I've finished the code to display it, so I know it loads.

Comment: @ Or Arbel, I have previously done that and the size was the same. I have been able to load it to the UIScrollView when I simulate it, so I think I'm loading it correctly.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. At runtime, using the debugger, verify that the `image` variable is non-nil.

Comment: @ lukaswelte, I have tried manually setting the frame by createing a CGRect(0,0,Image.size). It displays, but whenever I grab the size it is the same small value or 0.

Comment: @maddy it is non-nil, see image below

 http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/imagesizeb.png/

Comment: i have two theories 1. the code is in viewdidload and everything is without size yet or 2. the values seen are when you haven't stepped yet to the point where cgsize is set. In which Method is this code ?

Comment: @Caro your answer was correct in that I was in the wrong method, yet it made me realize I was asking the wrong question. I've updated it to reflect my confusion. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you calling self.view anywhere before getting the outlet size ?

Comment: @A-Live I am not calling self.view before getting the outlet size

Comment: Then the outlet is not yet loaded, viewController's view loading/unloading article should be helpful to understand why it happens  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html